# How to configure rbenv with ruby?

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I've tried to install ruby on my mac. Ruby is already installed :

```
brew install ruby
Running `brew update --preinstall`...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).
==> New Formulae
ghcup                                     reshape                                   tidy-viewer                               vermin
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 159 formulae.
==> New Casks
kindavim                                                 music-bar                                                presentation
==> Updated Casks
Updated 143 casks.
==> Deleted Casks
airqmon

Warning: ruby 3.0.3 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 3.0.3, run:
  brew reinstall ruby
```

But when i run ruby -version, i get the following result :

```
   /Users/oscar/.rbenv/shims/ruby: line 21: /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv: No such file or directory
```

I am using rbenv. I've tried to reinstall rbenv but i get the same error.
I am new in ruby and i need some help please.
How to solve this error ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed Ruby previously with `rbenv` and now you show that you installed Ruby with `brew`, which is a totally different process. I assume you removed your `rbenv` installation, but left around some leftovers. If you wish to continue with your `brew` Ruby installation, which is in my opinion perfectly good, you just need to remove the `rbenv` leftovers by removing your `/Users/oscar/.rbenv` directory, possibly you may also need to restart your Terminal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I remove all leftovers rbenv in path and on disk. Now i can get the version of ruby. Thanks